# Extracting a set of characters for a column in a txt file

Tags: linux, grep

I have a bed file (what is a txt file formed by columns separated by tabs). The fourth column has a name followed by numbers. Using the command line (Linux), I would like to get these names without repetition. A provided an example below.

This is my file:

```
$head example.bed
1       2160195 2161184 SKI_1.2160205.2161174
1       2234406 2234552 SKI_1.2234416.2234542
1       2234713 2234849 SKI_1.2234723.2234839
1       2235268 2235551 SKI_1.2235278.2235541
1       2235721 2236034 SKI_1.2235731.2236024
1       2237448 2237699 SKI_1.2237458.2237689
1       2238005 2238214 SKI_1.2238015.2238204
1       9770503 9770664 PIK3CD_1.9770513.9770654
1       9775588 9775837 PIK3CD_1.9775598.9775827
1       9775896 9776146 PIK3CD_1.9775906.9776136
...
```

My list should look like this:

```
SKI_1
PIK3CD_1
...
```

Could please help me with the code I need to use?

I found the solution years ago with grep but I have lost the document in which I used to save all useful codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `so.txt`:

```
1       2160195 2161184 SKI_1.2160205.2161174
1       2234406 2234552 SKI_1.2234416.2234542
1       2234713 2234849 SKI_1.2234723.2234839
1       2235268 2235551 SKI_1.2235278.2235541
1       2235721 2236034 SKI_1.2235731.2236024
1       2237448 2237699 SKI_1.2237458.2237689
1       2238005 2238214 SKI_1.2238015.2238204
1       9770503 9770664 PIK3CD_1.9770513.9770654
1       9775588 9775837 PIK3CD_1.9775598.9775827
1       9775896 9776146 PIK3CD_1.9775906.9776136
```

Then the following command should do the trick:

```shell
cat so.txt | awk '{split($4,f,".");print f[1];}' | sort -u
```

1. `$4` is the 4th column
2. We split the 4th column on the `.` character. The result is put into the `f` array
3. Finally we filter out the duplicates with `sort -u`

Answer (score 1):

With data in the file bed and using awk:

```
awk 'NR>1 { split($4,arr,".");bed[arr[1]]="" } END { for (i in bed) { print i } }' bed
```

Ignore the first line and then split the 4th space delimited field into the array arr based on "." put the first index of this array into another bed array. In the end block, loop through the bed array and print the indexes.

Comment: I got an error  $ head |  awk 'NR>1 { split($4,arr,"."); example.bed [arr[1]]="" } END { for (i in  example.bed) { print i } }'  example.bed
awk: NR>1 { split($4,arr,"."); example.bed [arr[1]]="" } END { for (i in  example.bed) { print i } }
awk:                                        ^ syntax error
awk: NR>1 { split($4,arr,"."); example.bed [arr[1]]="" } END { for (i in  example.bed) { print i } }
awk:                                                                                         ^ syntax error

Comment: Don't put full stops in the array name.

Comment: Do you mean, just putting the name without extension, just example. If I do this, I got this awk: can't open file example

Comment: Just use my example and change bed for the name of your file,

Answer (score 0):

Using grep:

```
cat example.bed|awk '{print $4}'|grep -oP '\w+_\d+'|sort -u
```

produces:

```
PIK3CD_1
SKI_1
```

and without the `cat` command (as there are always UUOC advocates here.. ):

```
awk '{print $4}' < example.bed|grep -oP '\w+_\d+'|sort -u
```

Comment: I think it was close to your code but I have tried and I have got this grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]

Comment: What exactly did you execute as a command, and in what environment? This output seems like a `help` for some command..

Comment: from what you have provided as an example data, this answer (and probably the other answers) output what you expect.. maybe you need to enrich your question with more details, or more data, so that we fine-tune our answers..

Comment: I have fix my file, there were spaces instead of tabs. Both work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found this:

```
head WRGL2_hg19_v1.bed | cut -f4 | cut -d "." -f1
```

Output:

```
PIK3CD_1
SKI_1
```